# execute remote php script on LEMP server

Tags: php, plugins

i'm developping a webportal and i'de like user to upload their own php script
to expand with function their personal area.
Each user will have a personal subdomain like myusername.webportal.ext
for security reason, it will be better if user upload their plugin on a different server.

Every Plugin should be like this :

```
/myplugin/
/myplugin/img/
/myplugin/sql/db.sql
/myplugin/js/
/myplugin/css
/myplugin/php
/* this for the backoffice */
/myplugin/admin/
/myplugin/admin/php
/myplugin/admin/..
```

Now, i have a LEMP server that runs myusername.webportal.ext
and an other server with uploaded plugin.
How could i do to let LEMP server execute remote plugin with out any risk ?
Is there any better way to do this ?

for example, uploaded plugin could be a "Tell a frined function".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without any risk is really not possible, but you can use less risky methods like securing your remote call by tricky procedures, doing some validation on server and client side, or writing some kind of custom protocol.  However, those take a lot of time.  You may want to look into `ssh` or `rexec` commands for Linux.